# Geometric intuition for convex combination in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus

I think I have some intuition for why the triangle generated by two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be given as the set of convex combinations. However, for $\mathbb{R}^3$, I am having a harder time. Consider the picture below. It is the “pyramid” generated by three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (or, the three vertices $u, v, w$ together with the origin as the fourth vertex).

How would I go about doing the following? And what is a geometric proof or visualization?

1. Describe each of the faces of the pyramid.
2. Describe the pyramid itself (that is, describe the set of points that are either on some face of the pyramid or inside the interior).
3. Find the volume of the pyramid.

[image]

My attempt:

For (1), I think I can find the three faces that are between two arrows (e.g. the face between the arrows $u$ and $v$) by reducing it to the 2-dimensional case. However I’m not sure about the fourth face, the one whose vertices are given as the endpoints of $u, v$ and $w$. I think it is $\{ au + bv + cw: a, b, c \geq 0, a + b + c = 1 \}$, but I’m not sure, and I’d like some geometric intuition/proof.

For (2), I think it is the set of all convex combinations, where the four points in question are $u, v, w$ and the origin: $\{ au + bv + cw + d \cdot (0,0,0): a, b, c, d \geq 0, a + b + c + d = 1 \}$. We may also note that this is equal to $\{ au + bv + cw: a, b, c \geq 0, a + b + c \leq 1 \}$. However, once again, I’d like some geometric intuition as to why this is the case and why it can be described by these sets.

For (3), I think I can use the determinant or something, but I’m not too sure. I’d also prefer a geometric argument if possible.

Comment: To see how to go by the third point, try to imagine the action of the matrix with columns $u,v,w$, on the standard basis, and try to find the volume of the simplex spanned by the standard basis. (*Hint:* how many permutations of 3 indices are there?)

Comment: You can describe the unnamed edges as linear combinations of the other edges. For example we know that the edge from $v$ to $w$, call it $x$, satisfies the equation $v + x= w$. You can find such a system for all the edges so that they are entirely expressed in terms of $u,v$ and $w$.

As for (3) the determinant is the signed volume of the parallelpiped defined by the three column vectors of a $3 \times 3$ matrix. Can you see how that related to the volume of this pyramid?